# Most orbital launches in one day

Tags: launch, record

There were 3 orbital launches on March 29 2018:

- Soyuz 2-1v
- GSLV Mk.2
- Long March 3B

Is it a record tie for most orbital launches on the same day (as expressed in local time)?

If so, when it was set?  If not what is the record and when it happened?

Comment: As the beginning and the end of a day is not the same all around the planet, I suggests either you precise wich time to use (UTC is one possible choice) or you slightly modify your question replacing "in one day" by "in 24 hours"

Comment: @Manu Local date was the same for all listed launches. That is the principal of the question.

Comment: @user3715778 I've updated the wording of your question to reflect what you've mentioned in comments. Since comments are considered temporary, it's always best to incorporate any clarifications back into the original post when possible.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_spaceflight#Orbital_launches_by_year Here's a decent timeline on wikipedia. (Says it's unsourced, includes failures, successes and non-orbital flights). Could probably filter that by type and get a rough idea.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn thanks! Using your link I found that there were 3 orbital lauches on December 21-st 2005! It is a good candidate for the record, I will try confirm if it is indeed the day when the record was set.

Comment: Haha should I just post that as an answer? Actually, nah, if you do the citations feel free to post it and answer yourself, I'd upvote it :). Shouldn't post something uncited. Seeing as the list also contains nations that no longer exist (don't think this effects the 2005 date) you may also want to consider who you're including.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to the link provided by **Magic Octopus Urn**, I found that there were **3** orbital launches on **February 14 1989**:

- Molniya-M from Plesetsk
- Kosmos-3M from Plesetsk
- Delta II from Cape Canaveral

The record was tied

- on **February 28 1990**
- on **August 28 1990**
- on **March 25 1993**
- on **June 25 1993**
- on **March 22 1995**
- on **December 21 2005**
- on **June 15 2010**
- and recently on **March 29 2018**

Answer (score 0):

There are currently 5 orbital launches scheduled for the 24 hour period starting at midnight UTC on 4th August 2022
There is also a New Shepard launch with human passengers scheduled for the same day.
If all of these occur successfully then the record will be broken.

Comment: Source nextspaceflight.com

Comment: ...and looking back from the 6th, did they?